# For loop dropping correct value after loop

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I need help understanding why my for loop will find the correct row number in an array but once it leaves the loop it puts out the incorrect value.

Code.gs

```js
  //Determines the row the Field Office is in
  for (var r = 0; r < dataValues.length; r++) {
    if (dataValues[r][1] == theFormObject.fieldOfficeFFO) {
      var q = dataValues[r][1];
      Logger.log('q inside loop: ' + q); //Row Value inside loop
      Logger.log('r inside loop: ' + r); // Row number inside loop
    }
  }
  Logger.log('q outside loop: ' + q); //Row Value outside loop
  Logger.log('r outside loop: ' + r); // Row number outside loop
```

Logger.logs
[image]

Comment: You need to break the loop, like this is run through till r reaches the value of `dataValues.length`

Answer (score 0):

You are right Robin, I was too much in Java. Of course you need a break. Otherwise the loop goes on until the length of dataValues is reached, so r is rizing. The **break** tells the loop to leave it directly without any further processing.

```
 //Determines the row the Field Office is in
 for (var r = 0; r < dataValues.length; r++) {
     if (dataValues[r][1] == theFormObject.fieldOfficeFFO) {
         var q = dataValues[r][1];
         Logger.log('q inside loop: ' + q); //Row Value inside loop
         Logger.log('r inside loop: ' + r); // Row number inside loop
         break;
     }
 }
 Logger.log('q outside loop: ' + q); //Row Value outside loop
 Logger.log('r outside loop: ' + r); // Row number outside loop
```

Comment: This answer plus @RobinGertenbach comment solved my issue.

Comment: Javascript uses functional scoping not block scoping

Comment: @RobinGertenbach I tried both "q" in and outside of the block and both worked. Learned something new and now good for future coding.

Comment: Except when using let which gas does not support